# Is it possible to make a file readable only for a specific executable file on Linux?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a https server, which uses a json to save the login information (registered users and hashed passwords), but I'm afraid someone may break into the machine and steal this json file. I thought about the solutions below, but I don't think any of them solves the problem:

- If I set it as not readable, I'll have to execute the website as root, which means if someone manage to break in they'll already have root access;
- If I create another user, that user would have to be able to read it too, so if someone manage to break in, they'll already be this user and be able to access it.

So, is there an optimal solution for this?

Comment: Yes, encrypt it

Comment: “So, is there an optimal solution for this?” - Storing the passwords in a flat file is insecure.  The ONLY secure way is storing the passwords in a database and hashing USER inputs to validate their inputs against what’s stored in a database.  Encrypted passwords can be reversed, through brute force, and thus is insecure. It might be an unreasonable amount of time today, to brute force the password, but it’s still insecure. Don’t reinvent the wheel. Your description of a json file is not secure

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, they were hashed, not encrypted, I miswrote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that whoever breaks into the server *through your website* will always have the same access as the website itself does. "Specific executable" does not help here, as the most common attacks against websites involve tricking the correct executable into doing the wrong thing, e.g. making your webapp include() a secret file into the HTML output.

The only way to avoid this is to make the website *not need* the entire list of usernames and passwords. Split the account-storage code into a separate app that runs as a different UID, so that your web app can only ask the "account management" app about whether a given username and password are valid or not. (This could use ordinary HTTP requests via localhost, or JSON-RPC, or gRPC, or whatever is popular for "microservices" nowadays.)

The term for this is [privilege separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation).

---

("Flat file" vs "database" does not make any difference in regards to security. A database – even a file-based database such as SQLite – only has better *search and update* capabilities than flat files do, e.g. it won't get damaged if the system crashes mid-update... but none of this has any effect on data security, because clear passwords can be stored in any kind of file, encrypted passwords can be stored in any kind of file, and password hashes can be stored in any kind of file as well.

That being said... if your webapp performs any kind of updating to the file, then *do* switch to SQLite instead of JSON. After you've done the aforementioned split into two services, all account-related code will be in one place, so this should be fairly easy.)

Comment: How come I never really thought about doing this? Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.